# Provide an example of a universal algebra A that decomposes into a nontrivial direct product in which each factor is not isomorphic to the algebra A.

Tags: abstract-algebra, universal-algebra

A subalgebra A of a direct product $\prod_{k} A_{k}$ is a **subdirect** product of algebras $A_{k}$ if the projection A on each factor $A_{k}$ coincides with the factor itself.
The **subdirect** product of algebras $\prod_{k} A_{k}$ is nontrivial if the projection of an algebra on any of the factors is not an isomorphism.

Question: Provide an example of a universal algebra A that decomposes into a nontrivial **subdirect** product in which each factor is not isomorphic to the algebra A (all product are isomorphic to A, but projection on each product is not bijection).

I have an example of such universal algebra: $C_{p}^{\infty} = \left \{z \in \mathbb{C} | z^{p^{k}} = 1 \right \}$ for some k, and some prime p. Where $\varphi: C_{p}^{\infty} \to C_{p}^{\infty}$ and $z \to z^{p}$ so $Ker \varphi = C_{p} \neq 1$

Comment: Really? I guess the Klein $4$-group doesn't count?

Comment: Maybe there's a typo, and they wanted to ask "... each factor *is* isomorphic..."? By the way, the first sentence does not seem to make sense.

Comment: "Semidirect product" is is not the correct term. The correct term is **subdirect product**. And you have completely botched the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intended problem might be this one:

**Question:** Provide an example of a universal algebra $A$ that decomposes into a nontrivial subdirect product in which each factor is <s>not</s> isomorphic to the algebra $A$ (all <s>product</s> *factors* are isomorphic to $A$, but *the* projection on*to* each <s>product</s> *factor* is not bijection).

If this is what is meant, then one could take $A$ to be any algebra  satisfying $|A|>1$ that has an isomorphism $\iota\colon A\to A\times A$. In this situation, $\iota$ is a nontrivial subdirect embedding and $A$ is isomorphic to the factors in this subdirect product representation.

For a concrete choice of such an $A$, one could start with any nontrivial algebra $B$, let $A=B^{\omega}$, and let $\iota\colon B^{\omega}\to B^{\omega}\times B^{\omega}$ be defined by $\iota(b_0,b_1,b_2,\ldots) = ((b_0,b_2,\ldots),(b_1,b_3,\ldots)).$

(The proposed example of $C_p^{\infty}$ is subdirectly irreducible, so it does not have any nontrivial subdirect product representation.)